# Possible to use CSS to change a link destination?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Im creating a wordpress site. The service widgets currently link to individual services where as I want them to link to the services page, which displays the full list of services.

Is there a way that I can target the 'read-more' button class with CSS and then insert the link to the services page?

Im building locally while the domain propagates, but the theme Im using is this one here http://demo.athemes.com/quill/

Comment: No. The answer is no.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had come across it somewhere but obviously not.